# Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on array

Tags: php, mysqli

```
  $author_content = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM post WHERE author = '$id'" );

  while ( $author_content = $author_content->fetch_assoc() )
  {
    $content = '<a href="post.html?id=1"><img src="http://itd1.mycdn.me/image?id=869556971587&t=20&plc=WEB&tkn=*PzRyN3OlodQ660m0B4oIo4M3kKs" align="center">'.$author_content['name'].'</a>';
  }
```

Пишет:

> [Sun Jun 02 10:18:09.317923 2019] [lsapi:error] [pid 1946075] [client
>   62.148.226.69:37464] [host history.kiselyov.ml] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   fetch_assoc() on array in
>   /var/www/user63337/data/www/history.kiselyov.ml/author.php:22\nStack
>   trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in
>   /var/www/user63337/data/www/history.kiselyov.ml/author.php on line
>   22\n

Comment: P.S. кодировку устанавливаю. И переменную author_content я вардампил, там есть записи

Comment: `$author_content = $author_content` название переменных пересекаются

Comment: @РустамГимранов ответом-то публикуйте

Comment: @teran, а вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Закрыть надо как опечатку, на каждый такой вопрос отвечать без толку.

Comment: Любой вопрос который состоит из сообщения об ошибке имеет право на существование, если только это не дубликат

Comment: Пользователь зашел, спросил, ушел. На комментарий нет реакции со стороны автора - проблема не актуальна.